# Applications of DIO (Digital Input Output)

Tags: digital-logic, io

I am confused about the term DIO (Digital Input Output). What is it, what are its applications? A simple AND gate accepts digital input and provides digital output, how is the AND gate different from DIO? Is there any difference at the output voltage and the input voltage in the DIO ?

[image]

**Update**

[Here is one DIO](http://www.contec.com/product.php?id=1612)

Comment: In my book the term DIO is not sufficiently defined to give an authoritative answer. It *might* refer to a microcontroller or FPGA pin that can be configured to function as either input or output pin under software or configuration control.

Comment: DIO modules are available in the market, I have posted one in my question now.  This is soled by the name DIO. But why would I use it?

Comment: A link would be more useful, so we can check what meaning this particular manufacturer gives to the term. From the attached USB cable I guess that this gadget enables a suitable PC program to read the status of I/O pins and/or set them to high or low.

Comment: The item you posted is called a Digital I/O "Terminal".

Answer (score 5):

Without a link, we can only guess, but it's pretty certain that the module you describe simply allows you to control digital I/Os from your PC. This means you can select whether each individual pin will be an input or an output. If it's an input you can check whether it has a low or high logic voltage applied to it (e.g. 0V or 5V) If it's an output you can set the pin to 0V or 5V (this is assuming the supply voltage is 5V)

An AND gate is a logic gate with two or more inputs and one output, if all it's inputs are at logic high, then it's output is at logic high. Otherwise it's output is at logic low. It's certainly a digital device, and has digital inputs and a digital output, so you can probably call it a DIO if you want.

**Why would you use it?**

You could use it for things like:

- turning on a sprinkler system
- opening your garage door
- activating an outside light
- anything that requires a simple "turn on" command, like a relay/solenoid

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like a school question to me, but just a quick info:
Consider Digital IO to be the opposite of Analog IO, it deals only with discrete values (0/1).
An AND gate is a logic element which has two (or more) digital inputs and a digital output. The output will go high (1) when both inputs are high (1), otherwise it will stay low (0).

As you can see, there are no values in between, we only deal with 1s or 0s, not caring about the actual analog value (which could be 5V or 3V3 or 1V8 or similar for high and 0V for low).

The input of the AND gate will no care if the value of one input is 3V2 or 3V4 if it expects 3V3 as long as it is within the specs (datasheet gives ranges for those).

Regarding difference: Usually not; the normal device will output and accept the same voltage range for input as well as for output (saying it is an AND gate doesn't specify this, it's just the logic which is specified). But of course there are also components which take some data on their input lines (e.g. at 1V8) and output them at another voltage level (3V3). Those are called level shifters or buffers and are used to interface elements which require different voltage levels (again, see the datasheets of your elements)

Comment: I think I could not explain my question properly. In  market some modules are available called "DIO", that looks like the image I have shown. I am not asking what is a digital signal or what is an analog signal. What I want to know is what is the application of such modules which are known as DIO. Also you did not clarify whether an AND gate can be called a DIO.

Comment: It just means that these devices can be controlled and are able to switch some pin to either high or low level. You could then trigger different actions with this pin.